# cloning a new object from existing in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a multi step javascript object like this:

```
const source = {
  prev: [],
  current: {
    list: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }],
    data: [{ c: 1, b: 2 }]
  },
  id: 12,
  next: []
};
```

and I would like to create a fresh copy of it.
I know if I use something like `let copy = { ...source };` it's like a shallow copy. So if i change those arrays or objects in `source` they will also change in `copy`.

Is there anyway that by de-structuring, I get a fresh copy of all items? or should I do it manually for each and every level deep like this:

```
copy.prev = [...source.prev]
copy.current.list = [...source.current.list]
copy.current.data= [...source.current.data]
```

and so on

Comment: Guess I understood the question wrong. Why don't you just clone the original and keep it as a reference? And do updates in the original later? Why do you need all the levels separated?

Comment: In a nutshell, I have a multi level object that includes other objects and arrays as properties, I want to have a  new copy of this object where all items are new copies not references.

Comment: Then my answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

There's an old way to do it, but still works:

```
var cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.stringify

```
    const source = {
  prev: [],
  current: {
    list: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }],
    data: [{ c: 1, b: 2 }]
  },
  id: 12,
  next: []
};

newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source));
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this simple solution. LOL

Answer (score 1):

You can deconstruct like this:

```js
const source = {
  prev: [],
  current: {
    list: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }],
    data: [{ c: 1, b: 2 }]
  },
  id: 12,
  next: []
};

const {
current: {list: listClone, data: dataClone}
} = source

console.log(listClone, dataClone)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple object containing objects, arrays, and primitives, it's not that much code just to recursively clone everything.

Just return the primitives, `map()` the arrays, and reduce the object keys passing the values back in. Something like:

```js
const source = {prev: [],current: {list: [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }],data: [{ c: 1, b: 2 }]},id: 12,next: []};

function clone(obj){
    return (typeof obj == 'object')
        ? (Array.isArray(obj))
            ? obj.map(i => clone(i)) 
            : Object.entries(obj).reduce((o, [key, value]) => 
              Object.assign(o, {[key]: clone(value)}), {})  
        : obj

}

let a_clone = clone(source)
console.log(JSON.stringify(a_clone, null, 2))


// is the clone deep? should be false
console.log(a_clone.prev === source.prev)
console.log(a_clone.current.list === source.current.list)
```